# Formulario de edición de un nodo de neo4j en Spring Boot con Thymeleaf genera error al consultar relación

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, neo4j

estoy tratando de hacer un CRUD de un nodo de Neo4j utilizando Spring Boot. Para esto, seleccioné Spring Data Neo4j en los starters de Eclipse y creé un mantenedor con Thymeleaf.
Al intentar editar el nodo cuando ya tienen una relación asignada, me genera el siguiente error:

```
2020-02-05 21:33:50.410 ERROR 27792 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-7] Exception processing template "pregunta/view": Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringSelectFieldTagProcessor' (template: "pregunta/view" - line 20, col 23)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringSelectFieldTagProcessor' (template: "pregunta/view" - line 20, col 23)
   at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:592) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [@org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship cl.fjborquez.preguntas.domain.Categoria] to type [java.lang.String] for value 'cl.fjborquez.preguntas.domain.Categoria@7b1472e6'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65 cannot be cast to org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession
   at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:47) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.formatFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:130) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:229) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:129) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65 cannot be cast to org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession
   at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(Neo4jRepositoryFactory.java:95) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.3.0.M2.jar:5.3.0.M2]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getEntityInformation(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.M2.jar:2.3.0.M2]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.getEntityInformationFor(Repositories.java:184) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.M2.jar:2.3.0.M2]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter$ToIdConverter.convert(DomainClassConverter.java:239) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.M2.jar:2.3.0.M2]
   at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   ... 63 common frames omitted

2020-02-05 21:33:50.411 ERROR 27792 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringSelectFieldTagProcessor' (template: "pregunta/view" - line 20, col 23)] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65 cannot be cast to org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession
   at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(Neo4jRepositoryFactory.java:95) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.3.0.M2.jar:5.3.0.M2]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getEntityInformation(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.M2.jar:2.3.0.M2]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.getEntityInformationFor(Repositories.java:184) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.M2.jar:2.3.0.M2]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter$ToIdConverter.convert(DomainClassConverter.java:239) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.M2.jar:2.3.0.M2]
   at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.formatFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:130) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:229) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:129) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:592) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_191]
```

Al entrar en modo debug, veo que el nodo es cargado y la relación también pero por algún motivo que no he podido determinar, al querer visualizarla en el formulario Thymeleaf tiene problemas para mostrarlo.
Por el momento no estoy configurando el pom con versiones anteriores del paquete de Neo4j para Springboot, aunque hice pruebas que no fueron satisfactorias.
También probé con el driver de neo4j instalandolo por separado, pero tampoco.
Gracias por sus respuestas.

Edit: añado línea 20 de la vista pregunta/view.html.

```
<p>
   Categoria: <select th:field="*{categoria}">
      <option th:each="cat : ${categorias}" th:value="${cat.id}"
          th:text="${cat.nombre}"></option>
     </select>
</p>
```

Comment: Podrias compartir el contenido de el archivo `pregunta/view`? Especificamente lo que se encuentra alrededor de la linea 20?

Comment: lo agregué a la pregunta original, gracias!